# ASP.NET MVC2, can I use a model field as an html id?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, file-upload

I am a newbie in ASP.NET and html.
I want to upload a file, so I have a model with a HttpPostedFileBase field, and a strongly-typed view that gets the model in order to get the value of the file.

My question is, how can I send to the controller the value of the file?

This is my html code, I'd like to send the value of File to Model.File, but placing <%:Model.File:> instead of file1 does not work :(

```
            <label for="file1">File: </label>
            <input type="file" name="file1" id="file1" size="40">
```

P.S.: I've also tried using the asp:FileUpload but I don't what how to send the result to the controller.

EDIT:

Ok, I go for posting my code, thank you very much ZeNo.
Here is the Model:

```
    public class AddProductModel
{
    [...]
    public HttpPostedFileBase File { get; set; }
}
```

This is my View:

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Views/Shared/Site.Master" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<Application.Models.AddProductModel>" %>
```

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">

<% using (Html.BeginForm()) { %>
        <% Html.EnableClientValidation(); %>
        <fieldset>
[...]
                <div>                
                <label for="file1">File: </label>
                <input type="file" name="file1" id="<%: Model.File %>" size="40">
                <br />                   
            </div>
            <br />
            <p>
                <input type="submit" value="Add!" />
            </p>
        </fieldset>
    <% } %>
</form>
```

Here is my controller, I use the debugger here and it says that model.File is empty:

```
        [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult AddProduct(AddProductModel model)
    {
        if (model.ProductName != null && model.ProductDescription != null) 
            objRepository.addToProducts(model);

        return RedirectToAction("/AddProduct");
    }
```

Comment: You may checkout the [following blog post](http://haacked.com/archive/2010/07/16/uploading-files-with-aspnetmvc.aspx) for an example of how to implement file uploads in ASP.NET MVC.

Comment: Alternatively (and also a good read) is http://www.hanselman.com/blog/ABackToBasicsCaseStudyImplementingHTTPFileUploadWithASPNETMVCIncludingTestsAndMocks.aspx

Comment: Since this is a new project and once you get a hang of it, I'd suggest trying the Razor syntax and the jquery uploader to add some spice to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `<%:Model.File %>` instead.

Comment: Hi Will, I've tried using <%:Model.File %> instead and it doesn't work, what is it format? (I mean, has it to be "<%: Model.File:>" or '<%: Model.File :>', or just <%:Model.File>), and where should I place it?

Answer (score 0):

put you file control inside a form tag

```
<form action="/Home/GetFile" id="myform">
<input type="file1" id="file1"/>
</form>

<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
var form = $("#myform");
form .submit();
</script>
```

controller:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult GetFile(HttpPostedFileBase file) {

  if (file.ContentLength > 0) {
    var fileName = Path.GetFileName(file.FileName);

  }


}
```

Comment: Still not working, I've tried 

<input type="file" name="file1" id="<%=Model.File%>" size="40">

<input type="file" name="file1" id='<%=Model.File%>' size="40">

<input type="file" name="file1" id=<%=Model.File%> size="40">


And I tried with <%: instead of <%=, too, but the debugger receives null in that field :(

Comment: do one thing.. try to put <%=Model.File> just above the input tag. and attach a breakpoint in that line.. I think you might be getting Model.File as null    <%=Model.File%><input type="file" name="file1" id="<%=Model.File%>" size="40">

Comment: still not working... I'm starting to think that we can't add <%:Model.whatever> as id to an html input, can we?

Comment: We can definitely add any attribute we want through Model because ultimately it renders into some value. try to debug it... you will definitely get it.. or better post your ViewModel code here..

Answer (score 0):

Change your view to:

```
<form action ="/AddProduct" id="myform">
        <% Html.EnableClientValidation(); %>
        <fieldset>

                <div>                
                <label for="file1">File: </label>
                <input type="file" name="file1" id="<%: Model.File %>" size="40">
                <br />                   
            </div>
            <br />
            <p>
                <input type="submit" value="Add!" />
            </p>
        </fieldset>
  </form>
```

notice I have removed form runat="server".. also there were nested forms..

add this Javascript snippet:

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
var form = $("#myform");
form .submit();
</script>
```

in the controller make following changes:

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult AddProduct(HttpPostedFileBase file)
    {
       if (file.ContentLength > 0) {
    var fileName = Path.GetFileName(file.FileName);

  }


        return RedirectToAction("/AddProduct");
    }
```

Comment: sorry ZeNo, but I don't get it.
I need to pass the whole Model, not just the HttpPostedFileBase, so I'd like to pass the HttpPostedFileBase as a field of the model, not as a single value (in the method AddProduct I have to use a lot of fields that come from the model).